# React Router Error Render Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm trying to use the new react router (v 1.0.0) but I'm getting the following error: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

In this code line:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

Any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: At first glance this looks fine. Are you sure `App` and `About` are properly defined as `React.Component`s ?

Comment: Yep, this code looks fine your problem is in App or About

Comment: Can we see your imports/require calls too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably doing

```js
var Router = require('react-router');
```

This won't work with the 1.0 prereleases because of the way the exports are set up. Depending on which ES6 options you have enabled, you'll have to do one of:

```js
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var {Router} = require('react-router');
import Router from 'react-router'; // Works with ES6 import, not require().
import {Router} from 'react-router';
```